# Select from many-to-many in one query

Tags: object-oriented, sql, relational-database, orm

A common issue I run into when building CRUD applications is how to retrieve many-to-many relationships from the database and put them into an object model.

Say, for example, I have the following data structure:

```yaml
customers: 
  - name: bob
    items: 
      - chair
      - hat
  - name: steve
    items: 
      - hat
      - table
```

This is stored in the database like so:

```
customers
id | name
---|------
 0 | bob
 1 | steve

items
id | name
---|------
 0 | chair
 1 | table
 2 | hat

customers_items_link
customer_id | item_id
------------|--------
          0 | 0
          0 | 2
          1 | 2
          1 | 1
```

When it comes time to turn the data in the database back into objects in my programming language of choice, currently I'm pulling all three tables individually and processing them afterwards to create the objects and link them. Is there any way to reconstruct the objects in one query?

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is exactly. When you want a single query to return all rows from these 3 tables, you can simply `select * from customers, items, customers_items_link`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

You can issue a query that returns

```
customer_name | customer_id | item_id | item_name
--------------|-------------|---------|----------
bob           |           0 | 0       | chair
bob           |           0 | 2       | hat
steve         |           1 | 2       | hat
steve         |           1 | 1       | table
```

And then construct 2 `Customer` instances, and 3 `Item` instances, and add references to the items as appropriate in the customer.

That can be done in one pass over the data, if you hold a mapping of id -> object for both `Customer` and `Item` so that you don't create duplicates.

Comment: Worth to mention the [identity map pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html) ?

Comment: @Christophe that sounds like my final paragraph

Comment: Indeed. At first reading I had the impression that you kept this mapping local to the single pass whereas the object already might be loaded from another query.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you describe is known as the "n+1 select problem" and is referenced in ORM software. It would help if you dug into this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem-in-orm-object-relational-mapping

You either need to do a join and fetch duplicate data or do multiple selects. There are tradeoffs in both approaches.

Comment: Ah, having the name of the problem helps. I was wondering why I hadn't seen more discussions about it on the internet. I'll look into this.

Comment: interesting. The linked SO question mentions one-to-many. Isn’t there an additional challenge in the many-to-many where you have to avoid duplicating objects?